# How to sum string using Akka?

Tags: java, akka

I have a txt file with 100000 strings like ID;amount.
In this file I have 1000 unique ID. I'd like to sum amounts for each id and write these strings to a file. So the result file should contain 1000 strings with unique id.

here my code:
main class

```
public class Main {

private static ActorSystem system;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    system = ActorSystem.create("ClientSystem");
    system.actorOf(Props.create(ClientActor.class));
}
}
```

ClientActor

```
public class ClientActor extends UntypedActor{


    ActorRef worker = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(WorkerActor.class));
    @Override
    public void preStart() throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("100000.txt"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            worker.tell(line, getSelf());
        }
        br.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

WorkerActor

```
public class WorkerActor extends UntypedActor {

    Map sum = new HashMap();

    private String getId(String s){
       return s.substring(0, s.indexOf(";"));
    }

    private String getAmount(String s){
        return s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(";") + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object o) throws Exception {
        sum.put(getId((String)o), sum.get(getId((String)o) + getAmount(getAmount((String)o))));

//        clientActor.tell("", clientActor);
    }
}
```

in ClientActor I parse my file with amount;id strings and send these strings to WorkerActor, where I sum the result and put it to the sum map.
Now I want to write this sum map to a file, but cannot understand how to do that (How to know that all the rows are processed?).

Comment: in ClientActor after "while" I wrote  worker.tell("stop", getSelf()) and in WorkerActor I check if received message is "stop", then I should call WorkerActor's postStop method. Is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

Such a job would be better implemented using [Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala.html), esp since you should *not* do any blocking operations inside an Actor like you do in your simple example above; Those should be isolated using a separate dispatcher, such that the system can remain responsive even if IO is blocked. Akka Streams handle this for you, so it's simpler to do the right thing.

You can write code like this then:

```
val futureBytesWritten = 
  Source.file(fIn)
  .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString(System.lineSeparator), Int.MaxValue, true).map(_.utf8String.split(";")))
  .fold(Map[String, Long]().withDefaultValue(0l))({
    (m, v) => m.updated(v(0), m(v(0)) + Integer.parseInt(v(1)))
  })
  .mapConcat(_ map { case (k, v) => k+";"+v+System.lineSeparator })
  .runWith(Sink.file(fOut))
```

Give this section of the docs about [Streaming IO](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala/stream-io.html) a read and also read the [quickstart about Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala/stream-quickstart.html).

Comment: Thanks @Viktor for making the code sample a complete impl :-) I was too lazy last night...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any special library (eg akka) to solve this; you only need 2 lines of java:

```
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("1000.txt"))) {
    Files.lines(Paths.get("100000.txt"))
      .map(s -> s.split(";"))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a[0],
         Collectors.summingInt(a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1]))))
      .forEach((k,v) -> out.println(k + ";" + v));
}
```

Comment: for interesting definition of 2 lines... :) but nice job anyway!

Comment: I need to do this using Akka

Comment: @eis with fluent APIs (like streams) I generally equate the count of semi-colons with the "line" count, since from a strict perspective it is one line of java code. But I just noticed that if you apply that here, it's actually only one line! :)

Comment: @Emanon sounds like homework - no one should be mandating the use of a library for an implementation, especially when the built-in streaming library of the JDK is threadsafe, highly optimized and as you see by the brevity of the code runs rings around akka